# Wheel absent though I've just installed it

Tags: pip

I've installed psycopg2 and get a message that there is no wheel.
I've installed wheel via pip.

Could you tell me why there is no wheel when I do 'pip freeze'?

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+freeze+wheel

Comment: `pip` excludes standard packages (`pip`, `setuptools` and `wheel`) from `freeze`.